# PLACEHOLDER - Just a post to register my app

Tags: app, placeholder

PLACEHOLDER - Just a post to register my app. what else can be done to avoid error "Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write" please help. please don't suspend my account.

Comment: You already have a registered Stack Apps Post: https://stackapps.com/questions/9678/placeholder-workato-app-registration and despite efforts from the mod team to make clear that one registration is enough we don't believe this is fully understood by you. We don't want to see multiple posts from multiple accounts posting placeholders for the same thing. So you have to decide whether this post stays and you delete the one I linked to or you delete this one and that makes the other post the one and **only** placeholder.